# Problem using mosquitto broker with netcat

Tags: mosquitto, netcat

I trying to use mosquitto broker for an IoT application. I have a embedded hardware, actually not much documented/exampled on the internet.  I've succesfully implemented an TCP client on this hardware, and now i can send/listen messages throught any port i want via TCP and i listen via netcat. But when i tried to connect mosquitto, it doesn't accept the literal language. I digged on the internet. The broker take messages like shown below, but even this one not working.

I can not found any documentation. I even tried to watch Wireshark packages, and i can not find any pattern. Any help will appreciated.

```
$ echo -en "\x10\x0d\x00\x04MQTT\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01a" |nc localhost 1883|hd
00000000  20 02 01 00                                       | ...|
00000004
```

Comment: There really isn't enough information here for somebody to be able to help. Edit the question to show the code you are using to try and send MQTT packets. Also you need to explain what that output is supposed to be showing.

Comment: Also what exactly are you doing with netcat?

Comment: I have a TCP client, which sends text properly to any network device. But mosquitto needs CONACK signal, -topic and for those thinks it uses a hexadecimal language. I just wondered if there is anybody who encountered some circumstance like that, as I said before we do not need any code actually because it is a TCP client which sends what we've put on it.

Comment: That still doesn't really help all I can suggest is that you read the protocol spec http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar usecase like you and this is how I managed to decode this message and create my own connect request.
echo -en "\x10\x0d\x00\x04MQTT\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01a" |nc localhost 1883
The above message is broken down as follows:

- nc localhost 1883, opens a tcp socket to the mqtt port 1883 (to the broker (on localhost) listening to port 1883)
- \x10\x0d\x00\x04MQTT\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01a is the connect packet sent to the socket that was opened. This connect packet can be broken down as follows:

**\x10**: MQTT connect packet (Constitutes the control field with the 1st 4 bits representing the command type "0001" and the 2nd 4 bits the control flag.

**\x0d**: Remaining length: is the total length of both the variable header and the payload. This needs to be set after the whole payload is complete.

*Variable header = Protocol Name + Protocol level + Connect Flag byte + Keep Alive
Payload = ClientId, username, password, e.t.c, each entry is provided in the format lengthOfEntry + Entry e.g for a clientId and username and password, this gives: lengthOfClientId + ClientId + lengthOfUsername + Username + lengthOfPassword + Password. **Note: the length is always provided as two bytes.*

**\x00\x04MQTT**: Represents the protocol name "MQTT". The first two bytes 0x00 and 0x04 are the protocol length and MQTT is then the protocol. These give a total of 6 bytes.

**\x04**: is the protocol level. From MQTT specification, the value of the Protocol Level field for the version 3.1.1 of the protocol is 4 (0x04)

**\0x00**: is the connect flag byte. each byte is represented as follows:
UsernameFlag|PasswordFlag|Will Retain|Will|QoS|Will Flag|CleanSession|Reserved. 0x00 means none of the flags are set and persistent sessions will be used. Hence the payload doesn't require a username or password as will be seen in the payload bytes.

**\0x00\0x00**: two bytes that represent the keepAlive time. In this case 0 is provided which means that the server is not required to disconnect the client on grounds of inactivity. keepalive mechanism is turned off

The next bytes are already the payload. Since the connect flag was set such that no username or password is required, then we only have to provide the client id. In the above example the clientid is "a". This is of length 1 byte.

**\0x00\0x01**: represents the length of the clientId. since we have the character "a" as the clientId we have just the length 1. The length is always given in 16bit (2 bytes).

**a**: the clientId.

*If we count all the bytes, we come up to a total of 13 bytes which gives us our remaining le0gnth as 0x0d.
If you need to add a username and password, set the connect flag accordingly 0b11000000 = 0xC0. The username and password are added to the payload right after the clientId in the order lengthofClientId, clientId, lengthOfUSername, Username, LengthofPassword, Password. The reminaining length needs to be adjusted to reflect this.*

Tip: The variable header has a fixed number of bytes of 10. The payload length always depends on the data provided. the length of each element is always 2 bytes. so for the above case, we have a clientid of 1 byte and the length which take 2 bytes to give a total of 10 + 2 + 1 = 13.

I hope this helps you out and answers your question.

Useful links:

- https://openlabpro.com/guide/mqtt-packet-format/
- http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718024